# ALAssetsGroup, how to check if exists?

Tags: ios, objective-c, alassetslibrary, alasset

I have my ALAssetsGroup object. *For example*:

```
ALAssetsGroup *_someGroup.
```

But user can send the application to background and **delete this album**.

*Is there any check if assetsGroup is proper?*

```
[_someGroup numberOfAssets] returns the *old number of photos* even when the group doesn't exist
```

---

```
[_someGroup enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop)
```

CRASHES::

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSOrderedSetM getObjects:range:]: range {0, 1} extends beyond bounds for empty ordered set'

---

ALAssetsGroup has also `valueForProperty:` method, where i can get `ALAssetsGroupPropertyURL`
(Key to retrieve a URL that uniquely identifies the group). So i can enumerate all albums and check if some album with the same property exists. But it is available only in iOS 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution: `ALAssetsGroupPropertyPersistentID` property works as I expected.

So I can enumerate through the albums and check if they have the same ID.